# How to map objects using @Mapper?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm mapping objects using below code snippet

```
@Mapper
@Configuration
public interface CommentMapper {

    CommentMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CommentMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "Id", target = "Id")
    @Mapping(source = "remark", target = "remark")
    Comment getComment(CommentDto postDto);

    CommentDto getCommentDto(Comment post);

}
```

It doesnt map, but the moment I add this, it worked fine

```
@Mapper(imports = { Instant.class, DateTimeFormatter.class })
```

but not able to understand what it does ? `imports = { Instant.class, DateTimeFormatter.class }`
how its helping to map objects ?

Answer (score 1):

As it is written in [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.1/api/org/mapstruct/Mapper.html#imports--), with "imports" you can set:

> Additional types for which an import statement is to be added to the generated mapper implementation class.

In your case - it means that in generated CommentMapperImpl class, which will be generated as a realization of CommentMapper interface, two lines will be presented:

```
import path.to.class.DateTimeFormatter; // for example: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import path.to.class.Instant;
```

If you use gradle you can find CommentMapperImpl.java here:

```
build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main/your/mapper/interface/package/CommentMapperImpl.java
```

for maven:

```
target/generated-sources/annotations/your/mapper/interface/package/CommentMapperImpl.java
```